# How to show image (name) in DB using php,

Tags: php, mysql

I am facing a problem in showing images in my page using PHP. I have a table "images" in my db. I have saved the names of the images in this table which i am retrieving using PHP. My problem is that the images are not being shown due to unknown logical error. I have given both the absolute and the relative paths of the images in the  tag but all in vain. Please suggest me what wrong i am doing in retrieving the code.

My PHP:-

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/database.php");
$img_no = $_GET["img_no"];
$query = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `img_no`=".$img_no;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query); 
?>
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="project owl-carousel">
<?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
<div class="item">
<?php echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='img/".$row['img']."png'> ";?>
</div>
<?php }; ?>
</div>
```

In the img src, I have given both the absolute and the relative paths of the images folder, but did not work!

Please suggest!
Thanks in advance!
Regards!

Comment: You have to save the url image like assets/img/name.png

Comment: Are you sure that the images will be in .png format? Try using a slash before src src='/img/".$row['img']."png'> or src='./img/".$row['img']."png'> "

Comment: Always include the output along with your question, it helps alot. Paste the HTML being generated.

Comment: make sure that extension is the image. and try src='img/".$row['img']."png'>

Comment: yes, the image name saved in db table is image1.png. and the image extension is .png. i am damn sure about this! Secondly, my this code is not generating any error, it is just not displaying the images, therefore, i did not share the result in my post!

Answer (score 1):

Does your image extention(.png) is same to what you have written in your code.
if yes then check whethere you have saved your image name in database with extention or without it.

Comment: yes, the image name saved in db table is image1.png. and the image extension is .png. i am damn sure about this!

Comment: Yes Purushotam Thakur sahab, your suggestion worked, i was saving the image name image1.png with its extension in the DB and in the HTML img tag, i was also giving the .png extension like this .$row[img].".png'>";. So, the .png extension was being given by me twice. I removed the extension in my img scr tag and the the images are shown...! thanks for the suggestion!